# "git-svn dcommit" got an error after merged a git-svn repository whose remote svn repository is different

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn

```
| Step# | svnA                  | svnB                  | gitA               | gitB                     |
|-------|-----------------------|-----------------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
|     0 | svnadmin create svnA  | svnadmin create svnB  |                    |                          |
|     1 | svn commit -m "svnA1" | svn commit -m "svnB1" |                    |                          |
|     2 |                       |                       | git svn clone svnA | git svn clone svnB       |
|     3 |                       |                       | git merge gitB     |                          |
|     4 |                       |                       | git svn dcommit    |                          |
|     5 |                       |                       |                    | git merge gitA           |
|     6 |                       |                       |                    | git svn dcommit [ERROR!] |

[ERROR!] = 
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 856
```

I'm trying to use 2 difference subversion repository [svnA] and [svnB] which is almost empty (Step0 and Step1).
And they have each git-svn repository [gitA] and [gitB] (Step2).

Merging [gitB] to [gitA] (Step3), [gitA]'s history includes commit "svnA1" and commit "svnB1". 
After dcommit (Step4), [svnA]'s history also includes commit "svnA1" and commit "svnB1".

At last, [gitB]'s will also include the two commit after merging [gitA] to [gitB] (Step5) and [svnB]'s after dcommit (Step6).
But I got "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history" error while Step6.

What does this error mean? How can I resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: looks like git-svn lost it's svn context. At which point will `git svn info` stop finding it? My guess would be that after you merge A->B at step 5, B doesn't have svn context anymore. Maybe it can be fixed by avoiding svnA marks taken from the repository A.

Comment: You could also try linking both svn repositories to one git repositories, there are [online resources](http://blog.shuningbian.net/2011/05/git-with-multiple-svn-remotes.html) on how to do that.